# SOLID - обсуждение принципа ISP (interface segregation principle, разделения интерфейса)

Tags: любой-язык, solid, isp

Определение мне понятно. Но как его правильно соблюдать?

Дробить интерфейс на множество мелких и делать из них иерархию на все случаи кода, чтобы не было лишних методов в контракте интерфейса?

Объясните, пожалуйста, принцип "I" из SOLID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данный принцип гласит, что «Много специализированных интерфейсов лучше, чем один универсальный»

На примере:

У Вас есть магазин книги и диски. Вы хотите запустить скидку для дисков, а для книг промоакцию, разуметься Вы будете использовать наследование и интерфейс, вот и у каждого Вашего класса будут разные интерфейсы по скидкам.

То есть для класса ProductBook который расширяет Product интерфейс будет BookInterface в котором будет метод promo(), в то время как в интерфейсе CDInterface будет метод sale().

Логика этого принципа очень проста - не использовать методы которые Вы не будете реализовывать.

Надеюсь доступно)

Comment: Логика понятна. Но позвольте мне тогда ещё один пример. Вот есть у нас класс птицы Bird, его интерфейс есть и летать eat() fly(), но потом мы понимаем, что не все птицы умеют летать. В соответствии с принципом ISP как правильнее поступить: делать 2 интерфейса и во втором noFly(), или же в одном, но у подкласса как-нибудь реализовать логику fly() чтобы показать что не летает? По логике вроде первый вариант, но как-то непривычно это, так ведь не делают...

Comment: Только два интерфейса, который летает и нелетает. Вы снова упустили главный момент, в интерфейсе Вы не должны создавать методы которые не будут выполняться.